# Find the value of $m/n$

Tags: permutations, combinations

Let $n$ be the number of ways in which $5$ men and $7$ women can stand in a queue such that all the women stand consecutively.  Let $m$ be the number  of ways in which the same $12$ persons can stand in a queue such that exactly $6$ women stand consecutively. Then find the value of $m/n$.
I have done that for find $n$ I take all the $7$ women as $1$ quantity along with the $5$ men and they can be arranged as $6!*7!$ ways.
But I failed for finding $m$.
Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is easier to first find the number of ways at least $6$ (i.e. 6 or 7) women stand consecutively and then subtract that by the number of ways the seventh woman can be next to the six consecutive women (i.e. 7 consecutive women) to find the number of ways exactly $6$ women stand consecutively.

Let's say there is a block of $6$ women who stand consecutively. We can treat this as one quantity with ${7 \choose 6}$ different possible sets of women to include and $6!$ different internal arrangements. Then, we have this $1$ quantity, $1$ other women, and $5$ other men, so there are $7$ total quantities to arrange and thus $7!$ ways to arrange them. Thus, the total number of ways is ${7 \choose 6}\cdot 6!\cdot 7!=7\cdot 6!\cdot 7!$

Now, we want to find the number of ways the seventh woman can be next to the six consecutive women. There are $2$ ways this can happen: the other woman is directly left of the block of 6 women or the other woman is directly right of the block of 6 women. Again, there are still ${7 \choose 6}$ ways to choose the block of 6 women and $6!$ internal arrangements of this bloc. This gives us $1$ block of women and $5$ other men, so there are $6$ total quantities to arrange and thus $6!$ ways to arrange them. Thus, the total number of ways is $2\cdot {7\choose 6}\cdot 6!\cdot 6!=2\cdot 7!\cdot 6!$

Thus, to calculate $m$, we subtract the two above quantities:

$$m=7\cdot 6!\cdot 7!-2\cdot 6!\cdot 7!=5\cdot 6!\cdot 7!$$

From here, it is easy to see that $\frac m n=5$

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest approach is to hand count the ways to choose the locations of the women.  If they are at one end (2 ways)you have five places to put the seventh and if they are not (5 ways) you have four places to put the seventh.  There are $2 \cdot 5 + 5 \cdot 4=30$ ways to position the women.  Then you can order the men and women in $5!\cdot 7!$ ways, so the answer is $30 \cdot 5! \cdot 7!$